# Cannot find symbol when I try to create object in the main class for Java

Tags: java

This is my main. It's a program that figures out employees weekly pay by either weekly salary, base + rate,  or hourly + rate pay. So i was trying to create a object and then ran into this obstacle.

```
public class Lab3A {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee emp1 = new Employee (bob);
    }

}
```

and this is my class object.

```
public class Employee {
    private static int empCount = 0; 
    private String empName; 
    private int empNumber;
    private double empSalary;
    private double empRate;
    private double empHours;
    private double empBase;
    private int empPieces;
    private int empType;

    public Employee (String name){
        name = this.empName;
        empCount ++;
    }

    public void setEmployeePay (double salary){
        salary= this.empSalary;
    }

    public void setEmployeePay (double rate, double hours){
        rate = this.empRate;
        hours = this.empHours;
    }

    public void setEmployeePay (double base, int pieces){
        base = this.empBase;
        pieces = this.empPieces;
    }

    public static int getCount (){
        return empCount;
    }

    public String getName(){
         return empName;
    }

    public int getNumber (int max, int min){
        return ((int) (Math.random()*(max - min))) + min;
    }
    public double calculatePay(){
        if (empCount == 1)
        {
            if (empHours > 0 && empRate > 0){
                double pay = (empHours - 40) * 1.5;
                return pay;
            } else {
                double pay = empRate * empHours;
                return pay;
            }
        } else if (empSalary > 0){
            double pay = empSalary / 52;
            return pay;
        } else {
            double pay = empBase + empPieces * 24;
            return pay;
        }

    }
}
```

would appreciate if someone could clarify what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: I highly suggest to close this question because the author apparently didn't put any effort to solve the issue before asking.

Comment: Change name = this.empName; in your Employee class to this.empName = name;

Comment: What's up with your indentation? Indentation is supposed to make the code _easier_ to read

Answer (score 1):

You need `"bob"`, not just `bob`.

`"bob"` is considered a String Literal. `bob` alone is being interpreted as a variable identifier, and you have no variable labeled `bob`.

You could alternatively create a `String` variable named `bob` before you create the object:

```
String bob = "bob";
Employee employee = new Employee(bob);
```

But in a situation like this, it would be better to label the variable as `name`, since it represents a name.

Comment: haha wow I feel so stupid, I should've known that. Thanks for the help bud :)